# SSIS execute stored procedure from centralized server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I created a SSIS package which is deployed in my centralized SQL Server. There is a stored procedure written in centralized Server which clean the data from tables. Now my SSIS package from centralized Server is connecting to multiple servers and I need to execute that stored procedure to clean the data.

I don't have any linked servers as I got connecting strings to multiple servers from centralized tables.

How can I execute the stored procedure and do my task in other servers?

Comment: If it's a SSIS package, then the server the package uses in its data sources can be parametrised or environmentalised.

Comment: @Larnu, Could you please elaborate ? Yes it's a SSIS package.

Comment: that stored procedure (and any objects in the SP) would need to exist on those other servers in order to be run on them.

Comment: take a execute script. give your desired data source. from the execute script call the procedure. i